# How to use React Native Switch inside a functional component?

Tags: react-native, state, toggle

I am trying to use the **Switch** component provided by **react-native**, but it doesn't toggle.

```
function settings(props) {
    let {changeView, header} = props;
    let rememberPin = false;
    let toggleRememberPin = (value) => {
        rememberPin = value;
    };
    return (
        <View style={styles.appContainer}>
            <View style={styles.appBody}>
                <View style={{flex:1, flexDirection: 'row',justifyContent:'center',alignItems:'center',width: Dimensions.get('screen').width,backgroundColor: Colors.white}}>
                    <Text>Remember PIN:</Text>
                    <Switch
                        onValueChange={toggleRememberPin}
                        value={rememberPin}
                        ios_backgroundColor="#aeaeae"
                        trackColor={{true: Colors.customerGreen, false: '#aeaeae',}}/>
                </View>
            </View>
        </View>
    );
}
```

I get the Switch rendered in the View, I can touch it and it moves from OFF to ON, but suddently it come back to OFF without keeping on ON state.

What's wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to look into the core concepts of React, particularly how component state works.

In short, normal variable assignment doesn't cause a component to re-render and reflect changes. That's when you want to use the concept of state.

Here's how to do it properly:

```js
function Settings(props) {
    let {changeView, header} = props;
    const [rememberPin, setRememberPin] = useState(false);

    const toggleRememberPin = (value) => {
        setRememberPin(value);
    };

    return (
        <View style={styles.appContainer}>
            <View style={styles.appBody}>
                <View style={{flex:1, flexDirection: 'row',justifyContent:'center',alignItems:'center',width: Dimensions.get('screen').width,backgroundColor: Colors.white}}>
                    <Text>Remember PIN:</Text>
                    <Switch
                        onValueChange={toggleRememberPin}
                        value={rememberPin}
                        ios_backgroundColor="#aeaeae"
                        trackColor={{true: Colors.customerGreen, false: '#aeaeae',}}/>
                </View>
            </View>
        </View>
    );
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately I am getting Invariant Violation: Invalid hook call. How to debug?

Comment: Can you share the relevant code in a Snack? I don't think the error is coming from my solution.

Comment: Yes, thanks! If you want, you can give a look [here](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/13991#issuecomment-592185620) on GitHub where I posted a detailed description of the problem. Any help is really appreciated

Comment: I just replied to you, but I'll explain again here in short: you were calling your `Settings` function component as a normal function, components should always be rendered as JSX. Since hooks are only allowed inside function components, doing this tricked React into thinking your `Settings` function was not a component.